# How export all icons from a Sketch file for iOS

Tags: sketch-app, icon, ios

I have a sketch prototyp file and want to export all icons with different size for iOS/Xcode. How should I do?
I only know how to export an icon/image with different size, but no idea what about for all icons or images. Maybe Sketch does not support this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Selecting all the icons you want to export and then make them exportable (right panel) can do the trick.

Here's a gif of me exporting three icons to three different PNG files.

[image: image description]

(sorry for the gif quality, a higher version can be viewed here (webm) : https://giant.gfycat.com/PeacefulShyJackal.webm

After a second look at your question, I realize I did not answer at all since you wanted different sizes for your files.

To export your icons with different sizes, you can add a new export option thanks to the "+" icon (see image).

[image]

You can then export all your icons with your export choices, here's the final result in my finder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After slicing them with right preset (iOS in your case), you can also use this icon in the corner to export them in batch.

[image]